# After creating hyperlink formula field, it is not populating to the record after clicking from salesforce

Tags: formula, formula-field, custom-link

After creating hyperlink formula field, it is not populating to the record after clicking from salesforce report

```
HYPERLINK(
   "http://e1ptrp.na.wkglobal.com:8601/jde/HostedE1Servlet?OID=Order_Number__c",
   Order_Number__c
)
```

Not able to save the above URL like this

```
HYPERLINK(
   "http://e1ptrp.na.wkglobal.com:8601/jde/HostedE1Servlet?OID={!Oder__c.Order_Number__c",
   Order_Number__c
)
```

Thanks for your great help in advance

Answer (score 1):

The [HYPERLINK Formula documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions_a_h.htm&language=en_US#HYPERLINK) suggests using this pattern:

```
HYPERLINK("http://e1ptrp.na.wkglobal.com:8601/jde/HostedE1Servlet?OID="
    & Order_Number__c, Order_Number__c)
```